# Custom cell isn't showing up when registered programatically with swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Newbie trying to learn programming concepts with swift and Cocoa Touch

So, I have once custom CategoryCell: UICollectionViewCell

```
class CategoryCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupView() {
        print("set background Color")
        backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }

}
```

Paired with one programatically created UICollectionView

```
class FeaturedAppsController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    private let cellID = "cellID"
    private let featuredApps = "Featured Apps"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = featuredApps
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        collectionView?.register(CategoryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID , for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
        print("Cell created")
        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 150)
    }
}
```

Code under App

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
    let featuredAppsController = FeaturedAppsController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: featuredAppsController)

    return true
}
```

**I've registered the custom cell in *viewDidLoad();***

Also, I'm making it's **width** to be equal to the *view's width.*
But all it shows me is UICollectionView with yellow color, that's it ‍♂️

Comment: does it print cell created in consol ?

Comment: you are using nib files for your cell?

Comment: @hardikdevios  it doesn’t. Weird, right?

Comment: have you set your delegates?

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh I’m not using a nib. Observe the register call, it contains a class. Which basically means I’m using a custom class than nib

Comment: @SandeepBansal i hope you have bind the collection `delegate` and `datasource` property.

Comment: @hardikdevios let me try. I’ll repost ASAP 

Comment: Where are your cells views created? show your collection view cell, have your added them inside the storyboard, where your collectionView controller is ?

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh I’m not using storyboard at all.

Comment: @SandeepBansal, Show you storyboard's view controller related to this.

Comment: In that case where is your cell, You have only CategoryCell class, and you are not using nib file or storyboard then how you expect your cell to be visible, I still wonder why haven't your code crashed yet ?

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh because these’s nothing to crash . I’ll link you when I’ll find a solution.

Comment: @SandeepBansal did you set the `FeaturedAppsController` in Storyboard? in `Identity inspector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. you missing some codes. you should have

```
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

and also u missing this datasourse and delegates of collectionView

```
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.delegate = self
```

this is the full code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {



    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        print("Cell created")
        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 150)
    }




}
```

Try this and let me know.
[image]

Comment: Will do so tonight

Comment: okay sure :) if its correct one please mark as a correct answer

Comment: It worked . Although, as I am not using Interface builder, I do not need to write @IBOutlet. Also, As I'm using UICollectionViewController, I don't actually need to inherit ViewController.       All I needed was collection          View.dataSource = self
collectionView.delegate = self

Comment: glad i could help you bro :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's all programmatically then init it with layout like this

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let featuredAppsController = FeaturedAppsController(collectionViewLayout: layout) 
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: featuredAppsController)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Where should I put this code in?

Comment: put this code where you present this VC or it the root ?

Comment: Newbie here. I've no clue what you're talking about, Sorry.

Comment: How do you show it if you don't have a storyboard start point , where you use this class , or is it shown magically!!!!, do you use **self.window.rootViewController** inside **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method of **AppDelagate.swift**

Comment: window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: featuredAppsController) this is under AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, if it helps

Comment: Have posted the code which I have under AppDelegate class! @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

Create your xib files and then register your cell with collection view

```
//Register cell
let cellNIB = UINib(nibName: "YourCollectionViewXibName", bundle: nil)
collectionView.register(cellNIB, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)
```

Comment: @Steven0351 but we both know from the code he is not doing programmatically :-p

Answer (score 0):

You are using **UICollectionViewLayout()**

You should use:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
```